# How to test polling with rxjs timer?

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, jestjs, observable

I have an angular component in which I made a polling in ngOnInit using rjxs timer, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  timer(0, 60000). subscribe(() => {
    this.getSomeStuff();
  }
}
```

In jest I have a spy on the function:

```
const getSomeStuff = jest.spyOn( component, 'getSomeStuff' );
```

My goal is to test how many time the "getSomeStuff" function have been called.
For example:

- after 0 millisecond:

  expect(getSomeStuffSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

should be true.

- after 60000 milliseconds (a minute):

  expect(getSomeStuffSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);

should be true.

But no one works, the expect pass only with 0 and I don't understand why.
I tried with fakeAsync anch tick(), I tried with VirtualScheduler and everything I found on other questions, but nothing seems to work with my case.

Anyone have a different approach to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you probably start the timer in `ngOnInit`.

If you call `fixture.detectChanges()` in the `beforeEach` hook, the timer is already running before you can spy on the function that should be called.

So either you move the timer into a function that you then call in `ngOnInit` or you have to modify your tests to call `fixture.detectChanges()` in every test (see below).

Also, you have to call `ngOnDestroy` or unsubscribe from the timer at the end of every test or you will get an error like `1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue.`.

So your tests could look like this:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  // other setup...

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;

  // don't call fixture.detectChanges() here.
});

it('test 1', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = spyOn(component, 'doStuff');

  fixture.detectChanges();

  tick(0);

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  component.ngOnDestroy();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found other problems, but you help me fixed this one.